# node.js + Express code critique

Tags: javascript, beginner, mvc, node.js

I'm learning Node.  I'm working on a personal project that uses Node + Express + Node-MySQL + Generic-Pool (for MySQL pooling).  I am new to the idea of module.exports and I'm still grokking it.

The following code works.  However I want to organize my code in a way that is logical and optimal, and MVCish.  I am wondering if those of you who have done this before could take a look at the following and let me know if this is the "right" way to structure things.  (Yes I know this going to depend a lot on the developer.  But at least knowing if there are obvious problems in my approach would be helpful.)

My folder structure looks roughly like this:

```
app.js
routes/
models/
base/
```

In my main **app.js** file I have...

```
var express = require( "express" ),
    mysql = require( "mysql" ),
    generic_pool = require ( "generic-pool" ),
    routes = require( "./routes" );

var app = module.exports = express(),
    pool = generic_pool.Pool({
        name: "mysql",
        create: function( cb ) {
            var db = mysql.createConnection( require( "./config/db" ) );
            db.connect();
            cb( null, db );
        },
        destroy: function( db ) {
            db.end();
        },
    });

app.configure(function(){
    app.set( "pool", pool );
    ...
});
routes( app );
app.listen(80, function());
```

Here is an example route/ file **"stuff.js"**

```
module.exports = function( app ){
    var model = require( "../models/stuff" );
    model.init( app );
    app.get( "/stuff", function( req, res ){
        model.get( function( result ){
            res.json( result );
        });
    });
};
```

Here is an example model/ file **"stuff.js"**

```
var db;
module.exports.init = function( app ){
    db = require( "../base/db" );
    db.init( app );
};
module.exports.get = function( cb ){
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM stuff";
    db.do( sql, false, cb );
};
```

And here is the **base/db** file

```
var pool;
module.exports.init = function( app ){
    pool = app.get( "pool" );
};
module.exports.do = function( sql, params, cb ){
    pool.acquire(function( err, db ){
        if (err) {
            // ...
        } else {
            db.query( sql, function( err, result ) {
                if ( err ) {
                    // ...
                } else if ( typeof cb === "function" ) {
                    cb( result );
                }
            });
        }
        pool.release( "db" );
    });
};
```

Comment: what is the last line of `app.js` supposed to do? It lacks either an identifier to replace `function()`, or the actual body of the function (with the required arguments)

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks fine.

However, you are not showing us much to review, definitely come back when there is more to review.

Some minor comments:

- Having your db connection config through ./config/db is good
- You probably want to throw an exception if `( typeof cb !== "function" )` instead of silently ignoring that
- The base/db code nests 4 levels of callback, you should look into queue management libraries for node.js